# Retrieving a process Instance diagram in Camunda

Tags: camunda

I have been trying to retrieve a process instance diagram from Camunda engine. All the JAVA and REST methods deal with retrieving the deployed process diagram. So, the closest I am is this method.

```
InputStream getProcessDiagram(String processDefinitionId)
```

But its of no use to me as I want to be able to get the current state of the particular process instance.

The process diagram representing the current state can be viewed in Camunda Tasklist but I have no clue as to how to retrieve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diagram with its state does not simply come from the REST API as is. Instead, data from two sources is collected:

- `GET /process-definition/{id}/xml` provides the BPMN diagram (which you have already found) [[1]](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#process-definition-get-bpmn-20-xml)
- `GET /process-instance/{id}/activity-instances` provides the state of a process instance in a tree structure [[2]](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#process-instance-get-activity-instance)

The tasklist has some client-side logic that renders the BPMN XML with [bpmn.io](http://bpmn.io) and places markers on top of it based on the activity instance tree.

Comment: Thanks, figured out rendering through bpmn.js library! But, the second method returns an activity instance tree but how to  retrieve the current activity Id from it? like 'Service task3' in my case. I see it as a leaf node in the result but how to extract it to render the diagram?

Comment: The leaf nodes of the activity instance tree are the currently active activities. Thus, you would have to process the tree to determine all leaves before rendering. Keep in mind that there is a distinction between transition instances and activity instances. Both may represent running activities; transition instances are always leaves.

Comment: @thorben Can I get the List of all completed activities for a process Instance along with current active activity instance

Comment: I got the answer by querying to History services by createHistoricActivityInstanceQuery by processInstance query

Comment: Great answer. Is there any example how to import the bpmn-xml and the activity-instances via bpmn.io? Currently I'm trying ```await this.bpmnViewer.importXML(this.bpmnDecrypted);``` . But how to add the activity-instances? [BpmnIoViewer](https://bpmn.io/blog/posts/2014-bpmn-js-viewer-is-here.html)